# Gradle task to unzip maven repo in Android

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I am trying to unzip a local maven repo and copy the files into `app\libs` directory. The repo is a .zip file and the zip file contains `.a` files and header files. Also, I want this task to run on `preBuild`. I have tried 2 approaches.

**Approach 1**
Throws compile error at line `zipArchive group:` saying that dependency `zipArchive` is already resolved.

```
android {
    
    configurations {
        zipArchive
    }

    task unzip(type: Copy) {
       def configZipTree = zipTree(configurations.zipArchive.singleFile) //If I comment this line, build compiles but the unzip functionality doesn't work obviously
       from configZipTree
       into "$buildDir/../libs"
    }
    preBuild.dependsOn unzip
}
dependencies {
       zipArchive group: 'com.example.lib', name: 'testlib', version: '1.0', ext: 'zip'
}
```

**Approach 2**
In this approach, I put the `unzip` task outside `android` block but now I don't know to make `preBuild` task depend on this `unzip` task. This approach works by running `\.gradlew unzip` but doesn't depend on `preBuild`.

How can I make any of the approach to work?

Comment: Are you sure you want to unzip a whole Maven repo, not a single artifact?

Comment: Repo contains just a single artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue.

```
android {   

    configurations {
        zipArchive
    }

    task unzip(type: Copy) {
        from {
            configurations.zipArchive.collect { zipTree(it) }
        }
        into "$buildDir/../libs"
    }

    preBuild.dependsOn unzip
}
dependencies {
       zipArchive group: 'com.example.lib', name: 'testlib', version: '1.0', ext: 'zip'
}
```

Note: This is not the most optimized way to call `configuration` since `gradle` complains that it effects build time.